# restoring alarm after device powered off

Tags: android, android-service, persistence, boot

I think i have coded myself into a bit of a corner here. but I will try to explain my issue as best as I can. basically I am building an application on android that is supposed to be a copy of the alarm app on the phone. I have an object that represents the alarm. it includes time, and days as booleans etc. i persist these objects by serializing them and saving them to a file. then, on boot, I have a broadcastreciever which starts a boot service. basically the bootservice has a loop that iterates over my list of alarms. iam trying to call a method on each alarm  object called "setSysAlarm()", which is supposed to recreate each android system alarm at the saved time. at present, the "setSystemAlarm" method is only creating a toast for testing purposes. BUT this is causing the application to crash. there is obviously a flaw in my design and I think that trying to use the app context is causing the crash. My thinking is that I should possibly create all alarms via the service through the GUI when is running, aswell as recreating the alarms on boot? therefore alarms creation can be done regardless of wheather the app is running, also the alarms will be created in one place ? below is my boot service code which is executed on boot.

```
public class BootService extends Service {

   private Thread setallarams;
   private file_acces_int  fileaccess;
   private ArrayList<alarm_entity> alarmlst;


   private Runnable setalarmsrunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
    for(alarm_entity alarm : alarmlst)
       {
            alarm.setSystemAlarm();
       }
    }
  };

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    fileaccess = new file_access_model(getApplicationContext());
    alarmlst = fileaccess.readFromFile();
    setallarams = new Thread(setalarmsrunnable);
    cont = this;
}

@Override 
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{

    setallarams.start();

    try {
        setallarams.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


}
```

and here is the setSystemAlarm() method from my alarm_entity class. basically this is meant to create a toast on boot but at present the app is crashing

```
public void setSystemAlarm()
{
       Toast.makeText(cont, "hi there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

if someone could help me out here id appreciate it. the methods i was using to get the context were 
1. pass it in from the bootService. doesnt seem doable to me?
2. cretaing an instance on of Applicationin the constuctor of each alarm_entity and using that as the context. this also seems pretty stupid to me. lol

anyway thanks in advance and sorry for the long winded question!

Comment: please provide the logcat output, we need to see the cause of crash..

Comment: and just for information, You Toast will not appear, even if the app does not crash, because You had forget .show() ..

Comment: oh damn.  anyway i cant get at the logcat as I have to restart the device to reload in the alarms.

Comment: also You will get the logcat....it just needs some time to appear. But if You wait long enough, the logcat output will appear after the device is rebooted with a lots of messages. Just select "error" in eclipse (or AS) and look for the error messages that depend on Your app..

Comment: yeah iam using AS. doesnt seem to be reconnecting to logct on reboot at all.

Comment: geting a "device offline" message first. and on reboot "device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device."

Comment: and did You get this dialog?

Comment: I have a Huawei Ascend Mate 7 and in my case it is like, the device reboots, then it asks for debugging and after 10 attempts, it connects to AS or Eclipse and then I get the output...

Comment: And, can You show us Your BootReceiver ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your manifest

```
> android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Joel  I never said that this is the exact solution, I also tried to sort out the issue and I did suggest what first stroked in my mind. You both are my seniors but let me tell you sir that pointing finger on someone's effort is much easier that providing the solution of false. sorry if I am harsh here.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, we´ve discussed too much for how You get the Logcat output :) . The basic question is, why You get this error. Maybe this is not the full answer, but I need to show some code. You are initializing Your context inside onCreate() of the service:

```
    @Override
     public void onCreate()
 {
fileaccess = new file_access_model(getApplicationContext());
alarmlst = fileaccess.readFromFile();
setallarams = new Thread(setalarmsrunnable);
cont = this;
 }
```

But like described in the API:

> Do not call this method directly.

I don´t know if this is the reason for Your crash, we have no Logcat, it could be any other reason. But it´s recommended to initialize in `onStartCommand()`, so put Your initializations inside `onStartComand()`:

```
    @Override 
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
   {

 fileaccess = new file_access_model(getApplicationContext());
alarmlst = fileaccess.readFromFile();
setallarams = new Thread(setalarmsrunnable);
setallarams.start();

            .
            .
            .
```

The other thing is, I can´t see initializing alarm_entity class, maybe I am blind (?), but I can´t see nowhere that You pass a context to this class. For example, if You are initializing this class, it must be something like this inside Your onStartCommand();

```
     mAlarm_entity = new alarm_entity(this);
```

Because Service holds context, then simply call `this`. Delete the `onCreate()` and then You don´t need to initialize a context, because the service has it allready.